# Resolve service by implemented interface without registering them explicitly in .NET Core DI

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

Using .NET Core DI, is there a way to resolve a service based upon the interface that the service implements, rather than requesting the actual implementation type from the container?

For example, given the interface:

```cs
public interface IHandle<T> where T : DomainEvent {
    Task Handle(T @event);
}
```

And the implementations:

```cs
public class Handler1 : IHandle<SomeDomainEvent> {
    public async Task Handle(SomeDomainEvent @event) {
        ...
    }
}

public class Handler2 : IHandle<SomeDomainEvent> {
    public async Task Handle(SomeDomainEvent @event) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Registered as follows:

```cs
services.AddTransient<Handler1>();
services.AddTransient<Handler2>();
```

Is there a way to get the implementations based upon their implemented interfaces, rather than having to resolve them by their actual type. For example:

```cs
var handlers = this.serviceProvider.GetServices(IHandle<SomeDomainEvent>);
```

I want to avoid the following (which works, but means that I have to explicitly write the event type):

```cs
services.AddTransient<IHandle<SomeDomainEvent>, Handler1>();
services.AddTransient<IHandle<SomeDomainEvent>, Handler2>();
```

Comment: Autofac provides `.AsImplementedInterfaces()`. You could probably create something similar as an extension method to `IServiceCollection` (e.g. `services.AddAsInterfaces<Handler1>();`).

Comment: What you're looking for is Auto-Registration, which is a feature that is not included OOTB in MS.DI. There is [a section](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-15/88) of chapter 15 of [DIPP&P](https://mng.bz/BYNl) that describes how to implement Auto-Registration in MS.DI using generic abstractions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to register every single implementation, you can use reflection to scan your assemblies for your type and register it for you. You can add and extension method to `IServiceCollection` e.g. `services.AddHandlers()`

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddHandlers(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    var handleTypes = AppDomain
        .CurrentDomain
        .GetAssemblies()
        .SelectMany
        (
            a => a.GetTypes().Where
            (
                x => !x.IsInterface &&
                     !x.IsAbstract &&
                     x.GetInterfaces().Any(y => y.Name.Equals(typeof(IHandle<>).Name, StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
            )
        );

    foreach (var type in handleTypes)
    {
        foreach (var implementedInterface in type.GetInterfaces())
        {
            services.AddTransient(implementedInterface, type);
        }
    }
    return services;
}


//inject into service
public class Test
{
    public Test(IEnumerable<IHandle<SomeDomainEvent>> events)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using this method, however I used [Scrutor](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor) to do the scanning for all `IHandle<>` generics and registered them as their implemented interfaces. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to skin the cat using [Scrutor](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor)

```cs
services.Scan(scan => scan.FromAssemblyOf<DomainEventsConsumer>()
                                      .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo(typeof(IHandle<>)))
                                      .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                                      .WithScopedLifetime());
```

The extension methods on Scrutor allow you to perform assembly scanning without having to roll your own reflection code.